# Firebase neither onDataChange or onCancelled are being called unless I log out and log back in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi I have ran into a weird issue where sometimes when build my app in my phone neither onDataChange or onCancelled are called.

My attempts to solve the solution have been:

1. Make sure all code is correct. I spent most of my time here but when logging out and logging back in fixed the issue I realized the code must be working.
2. Made sure the user is authenticated or else they are sent to log in screen. Since requesteEmail is initialized by FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() so I am assuming the user is remaining authenticated.
3. Made sure my read and write Rules where all open
4. Tried it with both addValueEventListener and addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Here is a sample of my code:

```
 private void UpdateFriendList(){

    String passing = "Users/"+requesteEmail+"/Friends";
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users/"+requesteEmail+"/Friends");
    Log.d("TAGL","my Refs VAlue is : "+ myRef.toString());
    Log.d("TAGL","outside THE PLACE above passing: "+ passing);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("TAGL","IN the datachange");
            populateFirendsLists(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAGL","EROR ");
        }
    });
    Log.d("TAGL","outside THE PLACE below");
}
```

And here is the logcat with parenthesis replacing certain strings for privacy

my Refs VAlue is : (app path)/Users/(user path)/Friends

outside THE PLACE above passing: Users/(Path)/Friends

outside THE PLACE below

When I Logg out and log back it works with the log statment and function being called.

Oddly enough relaunching the app doesnt change anything . So if its working and I relaunch the app itll keep working . But if its not working relaunching it doesnt fix it either. Maybe its an android studio thing? But I that doesnt sound right.

This weird bug seems to only occur when I am logged in and build and run the app. However building and running the app doesnt always make this glitch occur, just sometimes.

Do you all have any idea why sometimes this occurs? Im not sure what would prevent both onDataChange and onCancelled to not be called.

Comment: I have now also tried to reauthenticate the user and that does not fix it. It seems logging out is what fixes it  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); , no idea why .

Comment: any update on this ? i am getting same thing.

Comment: Actually yeah! So apparently when I installed firbase trough android studio there was a glitch that happened that I had to manually fix. I think it involved automatically refreshing the tokens, but this was a while back and I cant remember for sure. I forgot what I googled but I found a diagram that took me trough the steps no fixing it. I think it was made by google themselves. If you still need a solution I can try to find it on my PC but I am not sure if i still have it. Otherwise I would google for it or contact them they might be able to provide you with it.